# Make parent method return subclassed instance

Tags: python, inheritance, python-3.x, super

Say I wish to subclass Python's `set` to change the `difference` method like so:

```
class my_set(set):
    def difference(self, ls):
        ls.append(1)
        return super().difference(ls)
```

Now assume I also added `my_method` to `my_set` and I wish to call it on the set resulting from calling `difference`:

```
my_instance = my_set([1,2,3])
my_instance.difference([2,3]).my_method()
```

The above won't work since the set returned from the difference method won't be of type `my_set` but of the regular `set`. What is the pythonic way of going around this without having to convert the returned set each time via `my_set(my_instance.difference([2,3])).my_method()`?

**EDIT**

I just realised I could wrap the return set like `return my_set(super().difference(ls))`. Haven't seen that before that, so not sure if this is the right way of achieving what I want. Care to comment?

Comment: You would have to override `difference` on your subclass so that it explicitly calls the superclass method and wraps the result.

Comment: Using `return my_set(super().difference(ls))` isn't making the parent method do anything different, it's changing what your subclass does.

Comment: Interestingly, `return super(my_set, self).difference(lh)` returns a my_set object in python 2.x but not in 3.x.

Answer (score 1):

One thing you can do, is to create a `my_set` object from the result of `super().difference(ls)`:

```
class my_set(set):
    def difference(self, ls):
        ls.append(1)
        return my_set(super().difference(ls)) # <---

    def my_method(self):
        print("StackOverflow")

my_instance = my_set([1,2,3])
my_instance.difference([2,3]).my_method() # CORRECT
```

Comment: nit-picking maybe, but its not a cast (python doesn't have such a thing), its building a new my_set object which has performance implications on large sets.